# Use node module in typescript environment

Tags: angular, node-modules, typescript-typings, dust-helpers

I've been trying to use the node modules 'markdown' and 'dustjs-helpers' in my angular 2.0 client side. The thing is that I couldn't reach a solution using typings (both packages are not available on typings) and I wonder if there is a way to use them in angular 2.0.

I have to use them on the client side because I can't overload the server with many requests.

Comment: Create your own type definition.

Comment: you can always use the modules without typings.. it will throw error but will work

Comment: @GauravMukherjee You're right, strictly speaking, type definitions are unnecessary. Errors can be avoided by simply casting to `any`, although I must stress that this is *dirty*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple `type definition` file for those libraries.

Create a file `mytype.d.ts`:

```
interface Widget {
    render(): void;
    getInfo(): void;
}
```

Add this reference to your `.ts` file":

```
///<reference path="mytype.d.ts" />
```

Make sure the path is correct.

More details: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html.

Comment: IME "triple-slash references" are best avoided. Assuming you have a `tsconfig.json` at the root of your project, you can simply add any external typings to the `files` array, before your entry point.

Comment: @Andrei Zhytkevich Thanks, I'll have a look.